# Origine di "sono dell'opinione"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-origin

Da dove viene l'espressione *essere dell'opinione che* (o, analogamente, *dell'avviso*)? Ad esempio, da [Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/traduzione/italiano-inglese/sono+dell%27opinione+che)

> Anch'io, come lei, sono dell'opinione che, sul versante dei diritti umani, nell'Unione europea non dobbiamo applicare due criteri.
>
> Seguiranno altre direttive e sono dell'opinione che la commissione per l'agricoltura sia la sede ideale per l'esame delle stesse.

Questa costruzione apparentemente [è diffusa anche in tedesco](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58493/making-sense-of-the-construct-ich-bin-der-auffassung), e, molto meno, in inglese. A pensarci bene, è una costruzione insolita, perché, logicamente, è l'opinione che appartiene a me, non viceversa.

Comment: Anche in castigliano si dice "soy de la opinión de que" e in catalano "sóc de l'opinió que".

Comment: Domanda davvero interessante, @Federico Poloni. Ci vorrebbero ricerche approfondite, ma di primo acchito mi viene in mente una possibile origine in un contesto figurato, i.e. la personificazione di "opinione" come un essere umano che abbia la facoltà di "possedere" qualcuno. Uno schema di concettualizzazione simile lo trovi in "(non) sono di buon umore".

Comment: Uh @Nico, mi vengono i brividi a pensare di essere posseduto da un'opinione! :-) Però forse c'è un collegamento con frasi come "essere di un partito/corrente", essere dell'idea o simili.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Ehi, Linux ;-) L'analogia con il partito zoppica perché non si può parafrasare con "ho questo partito" a differenza di "ho questa opinione".  I rapporti di possessione sono eterogenei. Nell'ultimo caso agisce questo meccanismo: un'entità non animata (opinione/umore) viene costruita come dotata di facoltà umane. In linguistica cognitiva questa si chiama "conceptual projection" e costituisce l'origine della metafora (tra altri fenomeni). PS. A me verrebbero brividi ancora più intensi se si dicesse"non sono dello spirito" invece di "non sono nello spirito ;-)

Comment: È un espressione  più antica di quello che pensavo. “*Non ostante tutto questo sono dell'opinione di Bernardo Gamuccio An- - - Antiquario, ed Architetto diligente, che quest'Arco sia antico,*”  1735  - https://books.google.it/books?id=-5Q3NnIOkmgC&pg=PA110&dq=%22sono+dell%E2%80%99opinione%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvud637LrpAhUCxMQBHWB0B_YQ6AEIPTAD#v=onepage&q=%22sono%20dell%E2%80%99opinione%22&f=false

Comment: @Hachi Se traduco correttamente, alcuni autori dell'era moderna la usano in latino: in un libro del 1663 di un [autore tedesco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diarium_Europaeum), *in conscientia eius opinionis sum*, https://books.google.it/books?id=iL9CAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22opinionis%20sum%22&hl=it&pg=RA1-PA157#v=onepage&q=%22opinionis%20sum%22&f=false . Forse era già presente nel latino classico?

Comment: Potrebbe essere...si potrebbe chiedere qui https://latin.stackexchange.com/